# Does IndexedDB persist with a new service-worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, indexeddb

Does the indexedDB persist when I unregister a service worker and install a new one?

If I would manually unregister the service-worker like this

```
        navigator.serviceWorker
          .getRegistrations()
          .then(function (registrations) {
            for (let registration of registrations) {
              registration.unregister();
            }
          });
        window.location.reload();
```

what happens with the indexedDB that is created in my service worker? Is it dependent on the specific sw it was created in?

Comment: Service worker and indexedDB are different concepts. The indexedDB is maintained by the browser and related to the host. If you change a service worker and the host is still the same, the indexedDB is unaffected. To change an indexedDB, you need to change the version of the DB, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase/version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unregistering a service worker does not affect site storage, and that includes IndexedDB and the Cache Storage API. All previously saved data will persist independent of a service worker registration.